# AutoFixture auto setup return type of Task<IEnumerable<>> customization

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture with AutoMoqCustomization in my tests.

I have a service which is a dependency of the system under test:

```
ISomeService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<int>> Get();
}
```

I call it inside the system under test:

```
var collection = await _someService.Get(); // collection is empty
```

I don't care what's inside the collection, but I need the collection **not** to be empty. I do it this way:

```
_fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISomeService>>()
            .Setup(service => service.Get())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(_fixture.CreateMany<int>()));
```

It looks like it should be done with a customization. I created and registered one:

```
public class TaskCollectionCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
                new TaskCollectionBuilder(),
                new GenericTypeSpecification(typeof(Task<>))));
    }

    private class TaskCollectionBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            // never enters here
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it's Create method is never entered. Any ideas or ready-to-serve  solutions?

**EDIT**

Adding GenericTypeSpecification source

```
public class GenericTypeSpecification : IRequestSpecification
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public GenericTypeSpecification(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
    {
        var requestedType = request as Type;

        return requestedType != null &&
               requestedType.IsGenericType &&
               requestedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == _type;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `GenericTypeSpecification`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry, I thought it's a part of library, but it turns out another team member must have created it. See the edit please.

Comment: Not seeing any edit yet...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Forgot to click 'Save edits'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoFixture already supports Tasks out of the box, as evidenced by this [Characterization Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test):

```
[Fact]
public void AutoFixtureAlreadySupportsTasks()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var t = fixture.Create<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>();
    Assert.NotEmpty(t.Result);
}
```

Thus, all you need to configure a [Test Double](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) of your Service is something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void ConfigureMock()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISomeService>>()
        .Setup(s => s.Get())
        .Returns(fixture.Create<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>());

    var svc = fixture.Create<ISomeService>();

    Assert.NotEmpty(svc.Get().Result);
}
```

If you think that's too much work, you can also ask `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` to do that for you instead, like this:

```
[Fact]
public void SimplestCustomization()
{
    var fixture = 
        new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
    var svc = fixture.Create<ISomeService>();
    Assert.NotEmpty(svc.Get().Result);
}
```

However, personally, I'm not a big fan of auto-configured Test Doubles, as I believe that [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020), and Test Double configuration ought to be an explicit part of a unit test, because it describes the [Indirect Input](http://xunitpatterns.com/indirect%20input.html) for the test case.

Comment: Thanks. AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization worked indeed. On a side note, if there are both AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization and AutoMoqCustomization customizations registered it doesn't configure mocks automatically. Not sure if it's a bug or design. :)

Comment: It may be [by design](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter), but I can't say more since I don't know have any details.

Comment: @gisek Only one of the two customizations will be triggered, it depends on which one you apply first. Since `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` is a superset of `AutoMoqCustomization`, there's no need to use both at the same time. As a side note, you could also do `.ReturnsUsingFixture(fixture)` instead of `.Returns(fixture.Create<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>())`

Comment: @dcastro Thanks! I didn't know about ReturnsUsingFixture method. It looks very useful.